# How can I change the image(slider) one by one every 3 seconds in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title>Hello</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" type="text/html" charset="UTF-8"/>

<style>

*{margin:0; padding:0;}

.mySlides{
          position:relative;
    width:1000px;
    margin:40px auto;
    display:table;
   }
   
.number{
        position:absolute;
  margin:20px;
    }
    
.text{
      position:absolute;
   bottom:20px;
   text-align:center;
   width:100%;
  }
  
.prev, .next{
             position:absolute;
    top:40%;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    padding:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    user-select:none;
         }
   
.next{
      right:0;
  }

.text-align{
            text-align:center;
     }
  
.dot{
     width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:gray;
  display:inline-block;
 }
 
.dot.active, .dot:hover{
                        background-color:orange;
        }

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="mySlides">
<div class="number">1/4</div>
<img src="images/slide1.jpg" width="100%"/>
<div class="text">Text 1</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides">
<div class="number">2/4</div>
<img src="images/slide2.jpg" width="100%"/>
<div class="text">Text 2</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides">
<div class="number">3/4</div>
<img src="images/slide3.jpg" width="100%"/>
<div class="text">Text 3</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides">
<div class="number">4/4</div>
<img src="images/slide4.jpg" width="100%"/>
<div class="text">Text 4</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>

<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

<div class="text-align">
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex=1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n){

showSlides(slideIndex+=n);

}

function currentSlide(n){

showSlides(slideIndex=n);

}

function showSlides(n){

var i;

var slides=document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

var dots=document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

if(n>slides.length){slideIndex=1;}

if(n<1){slideIndex=slides.length;}

for(i=0; i<slides.length; i++){

slides[i].style.display="none";

}

for(i=0; i<dots.length; i++){

dots[i].className=dots[i].className.replace("active", "");

}

slides[slideIndex-1].style.display="block";

dots[slideIndex-1].className+=" active";

}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

How can I change the image(slider) one by one every 3 seconds in javascript?

I know that I have to use setTimeout(showSlides, 3000); What extra code I have to implement?

When I use slideIndex++; and setTimeout(showSlides, 3000); the image/slider changes in every 3 seconds but when I click on a slider button there I found no match with the slider/images with slider button. How to match the slider button with those images/slider?

Comment: You should rework your question, I think it's against the guideline to just post a link to dropbox without saying anything about what is in there - and personally, I'm not going to blindly download something. I'm not flagging it because you're not doing anything explicitly wrong, but if you want people to answer you should consider putting the relevant code directly into the question

Comment: Thanks Fabio Lolli for your feedback. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better use [Owl Carousel](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2)

self-coded sliders are not used in commercial development

But if we proceed with this, then [here is the working example](https://jsfiddle.net/u5tzmw67/1/)

I added 4 lines below:

```
var timer = setInterval(function(){
    slideIndex++;
    showSlides(slideIndex);
},3000);
```

It works, can't see any trouble

Did I understood what you needed?

Answer (score 2):

Though I would restructure your code, I think all you need to add at the moment is :

```
setInterval(function(){ plusSlides(1); }, 3 * 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.mySlides {display:none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="max-width:500px">
<div class="mySlides">
  <img  src="https://sites.google.com/a/bvsd.org/hannahisacornsnake/_/rsrc/1487361727251/home/snakey-pictures/Screenshot%202017-01-09%20at%202.47.56%20PM.png" style="width:100%">
  <p>Snake 1</p>
<p>1/4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides">
  <img  src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/VDfq9_C7lxXJAetQ_nuOZOWP89NcLK2DIo1jA3eKxlmLRsUp7FuZlAaXyoPh-1Ys9KEv3wzgCJantNie66YVwCnlpJjtwbz1AcnmiUagIcIb1E88ZPzKndZBav-4SIOalfoS1cwtVXmNg483z77BtZMJilnTBgOP_Gz1V8S0uTfLo_9vOK8UYGI5g6Uby7Y6uOarmgW013qz44X_VEI9yn4DIcqrpPV7wsuPxO71PZG6djseyXGF7wC4MBH3lOeJgK6pwKZb0dtQsr74EMsv9iK07jXBJVmXnSGY3MResvCNFBrViayvvxGyO0LcR4ZpdIxXEZI38VqbKArcs3-ieIYPWv4DQHQmM3KD7HYh6H4nR2lsyfLShyWPiIjJN2hgKsQtJajADxpI5IdCxA98rpYlq-xTPxxYNtTbWuf9SKP1NbffRx8J9jZgyw0r6BneO5LvgK_dHIEybpMrgJ2klPQBPaYuteFMOjzIQLX10cDF61Lib0jPM3LVPeey9OfRmRbN2vexZBB8Y0PZbAtAtDkMZnWDOzDUi1qqpN0CtJLgUm-BE6U_FCNkSsqIY7i9CUdjArWl=w1366-h678" style="width:100%">
  <p>Snake 2</p>
<p>2/4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides">
  <img  src="https://sites.google.com/a/bvsd.org/hannahisacornsnake/_/rsrc/1487361731357/home/snakey-pictures/Screenshot%202017-01-09%20at%201.04.24%20PM.png?height=241&amp;width=320" style="width:100%">
  <p>Snake 3</p>
<p>3/4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides">
  <img  src="https://sites.google.com/a/bvsd.org/hannahisacornsnake/_/rsrc/1487361723876/home/snakey-pictures/Screenshot%202017-01-09%20at%202.48.18%20PM.png" style="width:100%">
  <p>Snake 4</p>
<p>4/4</p>
    </div>

</div>

<script>
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 3000); // Change image every 3 seconds
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not sure if you want the dots though...